# Twitter bootstrap popover not working - reloads page

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, popover

i am trying to get a simple popover working through using bootstrap from twitter. i am fairly new to website design so sorry if my question seems trivial.

i have the following in the source code for my page:

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- Bootstrap theme -->
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="js/tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="js/popover.js"></script>
<script src="js/modal.js"></script>


... i have inserted rest of my webpage here....


<script>$("a[ rel=popover]").popover({placement : 'top'}).click(function(e) {e.preventDefault();});</script>


<div class="container">  
<h2>Example of creating Popover with Twitter Bootstrap</h2>  
<div class="well">  
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" rel="popover" data-content="It's so simple to create a tooltop for my website!" data-original-title="Twitter Bootstrap Popover">click to toggle popover</a>  
</div>  
</div>  


... rest of webpage ....



<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/holder.js"></script>
```

do i need to put any of this elsewhere? or include anything in some of the .js files?

nothing happens on hovering over the button and when you click it it refreshes the page instead of anything else.

many thanks in advance for your help,

Comment: Did you try relacing the popover jquery assignment with `alert(0)` to make sure your function is getting run for these links?

Comment: sorry josh, i don't understand what you are saying as i am still trying to learn how to code. Which bit shall i replace? Thank you for your help!